# Google Transliterate Result not updating in the scope for use in Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api

Need some help with integrating Google Transliterate with an angular project, Below is the snippet that make all the desired elements in the DOM as Transliteratable.

```
function za() {
      google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "transliteration"});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(procTA);
}

// calls the helper function for each of input as well as textarea elememnts in the page
function procTA() {
    procTAHelp('textarea');
    procTAHelp('input');
}

// for each element of xtype (input or textarea), it creates another attribute
// whose name is <xtype><counter>id. That way each element gets a new
// attribute name (which acts as an identifier for the transliteration process
// and a flag which check whether to enable (or not) the English <-> Hindi
// transliteration change
// if gtransx is set and is "no" then nothing is done, else it enables the transliteration
// most of the remaining code is a cut-paste from the help pages for the deprecated google transliteration api

function procTAHelp(xtype) {
    var textAreaList = document.getElementsByTagName(xtype);
    for(var i = 0; i < textAreaList.length; i++) {
        var attrName = "gtransed";
        var noTrans = "gtransx";

        var taInd = i + 1;
        if((textAreaList[i].getAttribute(noTrans) == null) && (textAreaList[i].getAttribute(attrName) == null)) {
            var tcc;
            var att = document.createAttribute(attrName);
            textAreaList[i].setAttributeNode(att);
            var textAreaId = xtype.concat(taInd.toString()).concat("id");
            textAreaList[i].id = textAreaId;
            var options = {
                sourceLanguage: 'en', // destinationLanguage: ['hi','kn','ml','ta','te'],
                destinationLanguage: ['hi'],
                transliterationEnabled: true,
                shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g'
            };
            tcc = new     google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
            var transIdList = [textAreaId];
            tcc.makeTransliteratable(transIdList);
                    tcc.addEventListener(google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl.EventType.SERVER_UNREACHABLE, serverUnreachableHandler);
            tcc.addEventListener(google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl.EventType.SERVER_REACHABLE, serverReachableHandler);
        }
    }
}

// Handler for STATE_CHANGED event which makes sure checkbox status reflects     the transliteration enabled or disabled status.
function transliterateStateChangeHandler(e) {
}

// SERVER_UNREACHABLE event handler which displays the error message.
function serverUnreachableHandler(e) {
    document.getElementById("errorDiv").innerHTML = "Transliteration Server unreachable";
}

// SERVER_UNREACHABLE event handler which clears the error message.
function serverReachableHandler(e) {
    document.getElementById("errorDiv").innerHTML = "";
}

za();
```

Below is the angular snippet that reads the particular element that is being transliterated.

```
$scope.makePost = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log($scope.newPost.text);
    }, 500);    
};
```

The Textarea element that is being transliterated.

```
<textarea
    ng-init="addTrnsEngine()"
    ng-trim='false'
    id="tweet"
    class="form-control primaryPostArea"
    ng-model="newPost.text"
    ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }"
    placeholder="Say something...">
</textarea>
```

So once Google Transliterate does its work and updates the DOM, I am trying to refresh scope with $scope.$apply() after a time out. All the words get updated into new language in the textarea, but the last typed word doesn't update in the scope till the model encounters a new Character.

[image: example]

Comment: Hi, I'm also implementing the same thing. Can u please help me out? I'm stuck

Comment: Google Transliterate doesn't work over https, so unless you can solve that, I wouldnt bother.

Answer (score 0):

Use the contenteditable div for input instead of textarea.

The contenteditable directive is:

```
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
return {
restrict: "A",
require: "ngModel",
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

  function read() {
    ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
  }

  ngModel.$render = function() {
    element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
  };

  element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
    scope.$apply(read);
  });
 }
};
});
```

Use the contenteditable directive in div tag:

```
<div contenteditable ng-model="text"></div>
```

[Here](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/editing-text-in-place-using-html5-content-editable.html) is the example how to use contenteditable div using directive. This should solve your problem as it solved mine.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the code in your answer.